# Best way to display JSON data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, dynamic

I have JSON data I am pulling in:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "0.1",
  "data": {
    "roomCount": 12,
    "rooms": [
      {
        "roomNumber": "204",
        "occupied": false,
        "permissions": {
          "roomCharges": true,
          "adultContent": true
        }
      },
      {
        "roomNumber": "205",
        "occupied": true,
        "permissions": {
          "roomCharges": false,
          "adultContent": false
        }
      },
      {
        "roomNumber": "206",
        "occupied": true,
        "permissions": {
          "roomCharges": false,
          "adultContent": false
        }
      },
      {
        "roomNumber": "207",
        "occupied": true,
        "permissions": {
          "roomCharges": false,
          "adultContent": false
        }
      },
      {
        "roomNumber": "208",
        "occupied": true,
        "permissions": {
          "roomCharges": false,
          "adultContent": false
        }
      },
      {
        "roomNumber": "209",
        "occupied": true,
        "permissions": {
          "roomCharges": false,
          "adultContent": false
        }
```

and I can format it just fine. using `JSON_Decode` and then displaying the `$output` in my `<table>` like so:

```
<table>
    <?php foreach($output['data']['rooms'] as $info): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $info['roomNumber'] ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($info['occupied'] == 1) ? 'OCCUPIED' : 'VACANT'; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($info['permissions']['roomCharges'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo ($info['permissions']['adultContent'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo '<a class="clickhere" href="display_room_report.php?id=' . $info['roomNumber'] .'">Click Here</a>'?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

But my problem is, as I have multiple php pages using this same table, I'd like to create a dynamic way to set variables, and then call out those variables in multiple locations. My goal is to edit the JSON parameters in one location and have all php pages update, rather than updating every single `key=>value` over several php pages. (something like this to set each one to a variable).

```
<?php foreach($output['data']['rooms'] as $info){
    $roomNumber = $info['roomNumber'];
    $occupied = ($info['occupied'] == 1) ? 'OCCUPIED' : 'VACANT'; 
    $roomCharges = ($info['permissions']['roomCharges'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; 
    $adultContent = ($info['permissions']['adultContent'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; 
    $roomReport = '<a class="clickhere" href="display_room_report.php?id=' . $info['roomNumber'] .'">Click Here</a>';
}
?>
```

And in my table display:

```
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $roomNumber ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $occupied ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $roomCharges ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $adultContent ?></td> 
            <td><?php echo $roomReport ?></td>
        </tr>
```

Making it a little more dynamic. So in case the JSON key and values change, I can change them in one location i.e. `['permissions']['adultContent']` might turn into `['guestValue']['RoomAuthorized']`. I could make the change in one location, and the remaining pages would automatically update.

The problem i'm running into, is that while I have it semi-working with the `variables` plugged into the `<td>`, like so:

```
<tr>
  <td><?php echo $roomNumber ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $occupied ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $roomCharges ?></td>
  <td><?php echo $adultContent ?></td> 
  <td><?php echo $roomReport ?></td>
 </tr>
```

I am getting the same key and value for each line item. Example:

```
204 VACANT  ENABLED ENABLED Click Here
204 VACANT  ENABLED ENABLED Click Here
204 VACANT  ENABLED ENABLED Click Here
204 VACANT  ENABLED ENABLED Click Here
204 VACANT  ENABLED ENABLED Click Here
```

When the original `table` I use, brings back the data correctly, like so:

```
table>
        <?php foreach($output['data']['rooms'] as $info): ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $info['roomNumber'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($info['occupied'] == 1) ? 'OCCUPIED' : 'VACANT'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($info['permissions']['roomCharges'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td>
                <td><?php echo ($info['permissions']['adultContent'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo '<a class="clickhere" href="display_room_report.php?id=' . $info['roomNumber'] .'">Click Here</a>'?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
```

And brings back:

```
204 VACANT      ENABLED     ENABLED     Click Here
205 OCCUPIED    DISABLED    DISABLED    Click Here
206 OCCUPIED    DISABLED    DISABLED    Click Here
207 OCCUPIED    DISABLED    DISABLED    Click Here
208 OCCUPIED    DISABLED    DISABLED    Click Here
```

Do you have any idea on how I can make this more dynamic? Thank you for checking out my question. Please let me know if you need anything else to assist me. I tried to explain it clearly, let me know if you need anything further.

Comment: Your problem is that the variables (`$roomNumber, $occupied` etc) get overwritten in your initial foreach loop, so they end up holding the values from the last iteration. The solution is likely simple, but you need to elaborate on how you are accessing this data in multiple pages. The answer may be as simple as phps `include` statement

Comment: I've tried that before and got down voted for it. It's really much easier to understand if you take 30 seconds to read it.

Comment: @Steve ah, I see... Yes, you are correct. I would like to create a "data.php" page, and include it in every script I need, such as include 'data.php';

Comment: Well a simple solution would be to just use your original code, place it in a file called `datatable.php` and include that directly. Or does the table/html markup need to change from page to page?

Comment: @Steve I think I may just end up doing it that way. The markup will change, but I can work around it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can read, the question is that you want to reuse the variables several places, but if the JSON changes you only need to edit it in one central location.

To accomplish this you can use mappings to map a variable in one place to local variable of your choosing. In line five and so on in the first code here, you change choose any name you want for your local array. If the variable in JSON changes, just change that one and your local mapping is still the same. Now you only have to change the code in the function get_data_in_my_format().

Create a data_parser.php or something like that

```
<?php
    function get_data_in_my_format(){
        $input = json_decode('your data here', true);
        $output = array();
        foreach($input['data']['rooms'] as $info){
            $temp['roomNumber'] = $info['roomNumber'];
            $temp['occupied'] = ($info['occupied'] == 1) ? 'OCCUPIED' : 'VACANT'; 
            $temp['roomCharges'] = ($info['permissions']['roomCharges'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; 
            $temp['adultContent'] = ($info['permissions']['adultContent'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; 
            $temp['roomReport'] = '<a class="clickhere" href="display_room_report.php?id=' . $info['roomNumber'] .'">Click Here</a>';
            $output[] = $temp;
        }
        return $output;
    }

    //Only insert following line if you want to run the function no matter what
    $data_in_my_format = get_data_in_my_format();
```

In the file you want to use this code

```
<?php
    include('data_parser.php');
    //If you did not initiate $data_in_my_format in data_parser.php, do it here
    //$data_in_my_format = get_data_in_my_format();
    foreach($data_in_my_format as $room){
        ?>
            <tr>
                <td><?php echo $room['roomNumber'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $room['occupied'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $room['roomCharges'] ?></td>
                <td><?php echo $room['adultContent'] ?></td> 
                <td><?php echo $room['roomReport'] ?></td>
            </tr>
        <?php
    }
```

Is this what you wanted?

EDIT: Changed the description in beginning

Comment: If ['roomNUMBER'] changes to a different name, to say ['roomID'], then i'd still have to edit it in two locations.

Comment: If roomNumber in the JSON changes to roomID you only have to change that in the mapping, so line 5 becomes:
$temp['roomNumber'] = $info['roomID'];
That is if I understand your problem correctly

Comment: Ohhh I see what you are doing, now. Yes this might actually work. I will try it and get back to you. Thank you @fiLLipnet

Answer (score -1):

Although it's not shown in your code it seems like you are looping through the items a second time outside the first loop which sets the variables thus, repeating the initial set values without actually "updating" the variables to correspond to the values in that row.

A simple loop including the variable declaration and the table output should do the trick:

```
<?php 
    foreach($output['data']['rooms'] as $info){
        $roomNumber = $info['roomNumber'];
        $occupied = ($info['occupied'] == 1) ? 'OCCUPIED' : 'VACANT'; 
        $roomCharges = ($info['permissions']['roomCharges'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; 
        $adultContent = ($info['permissions']['adultContent'] == 1) ? 'ENABLED' : 'DISABLED'; 
        $roomReport = '<a class="clickhere" href="display_room_report.php?id=' . $info['roomNumber'] .'">Click Here</a>';

        ?>

        <tr>
           <td><?php echo $roomNumber ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $occupied ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $roomCharges ?></td>
           <td><?php echo $adultContent ?></td> 
           <td><?php echo $roomReport ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php
    }
?>
```